# Can I get TFS 2013 to email users a test tool with instructions for testing?

Tags: team-foundation-server

So several years ago I was in TechEd in New Orleans.  It was there I was introduced to the Team Foundation Service - Microsoft's cloud-based version of Team Foundation Server.  In one of the classes on this, I was shown how to create a test plan for a web application from the Test tab with steps including URLs for each step.  The test plan was then e-mailed to the user for testing, where the user would download a tool which would open up and display the test steps.  The user could then click on the "play" button and it would take them directly to that page for testing.  They were able to capture screenshots, audio, and video with that tool.  My question is, is this functionality available in 2013?  If so, how can I use it?

I have created test plans currently, but I don't see dedicated locations for urls.
[image]
[image]

When I run it, the Microsoft Test Runner comes up but there's no functionality to capture the screen or audio.  Is this perhaps available in 2015?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest feature is the Feedback Client:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/give-feedback
- andd https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/get-feedback

which has gotten an awesome overhaul with this Chrome extension

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/exploratory-testing-previ/gnldpbnocfnlkkicnaplmkaphfdnlplb

Comment: Now that you mention it... I think it was the Feedback feature!  I did find the exploratory testing before I posted this question.  The Chrome extension looks awesome, but it's the Feedback feature that I was looking for!  Thanks a lot!